# Angular 4 routerLink - reloading current route

Tags: angular

I would like to ask it is possible to open current page again using routerLink.
I have this menu:

```
<ul>
  <li><a routerLink="home">Home</a></li>
  <li><a routerLink="users">Users</a></li>
</ul>
```

when current url is `www.domain.com/users` i would like to click on "Users" in menu and refresh this page. It is possible?
I know that i use `location.reload()` but it redirect full page.

Comment: can you explain your use case? cz maybe you can do it differently, but anw maybe you can try to go to some other route and back again to this route

Comment: I need it for refreshing all components on all pages. My components load data from api and user must have option for reloading.

Comment: instead of that you can make a function that making all those requests again, another option is as you've said, location.reload

Comment: I dont want to use location.reload. Can you show me what do you mean make a function that making all those requests again? I think i must create refresh function on all components (reload data and binding).

Comment: yep that's what i mean

Comment: It's complicated. I have a lot of components, it change structure of application. If I could reload components using routerLink it could be easy.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I'm not sure if this would work in Angular 4, but in Angular 5 there is an option for reloading the active route:

```
RouterModule.forRoot(routes, {onSameUrlNavigation: 'reload'})
```

Comment: this won't work for refreshing current route, it just allows to fire navigation event when the url is the same.

Comment: I use Angular 4

Comment: @bluray if you have angular 4 how did you use this solution?it gives me error.

Comment: Yes it gives error when you have angular 4. I'm sorry, this was good solution. I canceled acceptance.

Comment: In Angular 6 & 7, this is the correct method, but it requires a bit more work as described in the following article:
https://medium.com/engineering-on-the-incline/reloading-current-route-on-click-angular-5-1a1bfc740ab2