# Angular 6 router link issue in the same page

Tags: angular, angular6, angular-components

I have two links:

1. `['/productlist',1000]`
2. `['/productlist',1001]`

These two links are on the same page. If I click on any link for the first time. It is redirecting to the page, but if I click on the other link it is not working.

component.html code

```
<a class="dropdown-item" (click)="GetProductList(subitem.SubCategoryID)">
 <i class="mdi mdi-chevron-right" aria-hidden="true"></i> 
 {{ subitem.SubCategoryName}}
</a> 

GetProductList(SubCategoryID){ 
    this.router.navigate(['/productlist',SubCategoryID]); 
}
```

Comment: Please share your code.

Comment: component.html code

<a class="dropdown-item" (click)="GetProductList(subitem.SubCategoryID)">
                                          <i class="mdi mdi-chevron-right" aria-hidden="true"></i> {{ subitem.SubCategoryName}} </a>

GetProductList(SubCategoryID){
    this.router.navigate(['/productlist',SubCategoryID]);
  }

i am binding the values dynamically for the link

Comment: Very similar question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48446261/force-routerlink-to-refresh-component

Comment: Add that code to the question please.

Comment: Edit the post and add the code to it.

Answer (score 5):

Since for angular it is same route - it is not reloaded.

Two possible solutions:

1. In component subscribe to this.route.params and react accordingly, like in [Angular 4 routerLink - reloading current route](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50127475/angular-4-routerlink-reloading-current-route)
2. in Angular 5 there is an option for reloading the active route:

RouterModule.forRoot(routes, {onSameUrlNavigation: ‘reload’}

Try it

Comment: onSameUrlNavigation does not trigger lifecycles, only guards and resolvers see https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/21115"

Answer (score 3):

ok, there is many unnecessary hacks for this (even dangerous due to memory leaks...), but the proper (intended) way, is to subscribe to the route's param change, then the binded form should update when you reload your data:

```
ngOnInit() {
  this.route.paramMap.subscribe(params => {
     this.myParam = params.get("id");
     this.loadData();
  })
}
```

note: the route here is the **ActivatedRoute** imported from '@angular/router';

but, If you still want full refresh, you can setup to a dummy root/component, that will redirect you back.

Answer (score 0):

For me this worked NgOnit was not called by naviagting to same route so i used subscribe in constructor and it worked like charm

```
  constructor(private route: ActivatedRout) {
         route.params.subscribe(val => {
            ///  your NgOnit code
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
import { NgModule, Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Routes, RouterModule, RouteReuseStrategy, ActivatedRouteSnapshot, DetachedRouteHandle } from '@angular/router';

const routes: Routes = [
  
];
@Injectable()
export class MyStrategy extends RouteReuseStrategy {
   shouldDetach(route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot): boolean {
    return false;
  }
  store(route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot, detachedTree: DetachedRouteHandle): void {}
  shouldAttach(route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot): boolean {
    return false;
  }
  retrieve(route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot): DetachedRouteHandle|null {
    return null;
  }
  shouldReuseRoute(future: ActivatedRouteSnapshot, curr: ActivatedRouteSnapshot): boolean {
    return false;
  }
}
@NgModule({
  imports: [
    RouterModule.forRoot(routes, { scrollPositionRestoration: 'enabled', initialNavigation: 'enabled' , onSameUrlNavigation: 'reload'}),
  ],
  providers: [{provide: RouteReuseStrategy, useClass: MyStrategy}],
  exports: [RouterModule],
})
export class AppRoutingModule {}
```

Comment: Try this approach with onSameUrlNavigation: 'reload' and RouteReuseStrategy

Answer (score 0):

I have solved it using a different alias for the same page on the router.

If the original path is like this:

```
<a [routerLinkActive]="['active']" [routerLink]="['/listapersonas', tokenid]">Link</a>

{ path: 'listapersonas' , component: ListaPersonasComponent, canActivate: [ AuthGuardRole ] },
```

It is possible to redirect to the same place like this:

```
<a [routerLinkActive]="['active']" [routerLink]="['/listapersonasotheralias', tokenid]">Link</a>

{ path: 'listapersonasotheralias' , component: ListaPersonasComponent, canActivate: [ AuthGuardRole ] },
```

Anyway it's a cheat, not a solution.

Answer (score -1):

**Try this way.**

```
<a [routerLink]="['/productlist']" [queryParams]="{id: 1}"> // Set dynamic
   link
</a>
```

**Another way is :**

```
<a  [routerLink]="[ '/productlist',1000]">Link</a>
```

By this way you don't need to call any function. [For more information](https://angular.io/api/router/RouterLink)
please read this.

Comment: @maruthi burkani Can you please update your status on answer ?