# Navigating to same page after performing a operation

Tags: angular, routes

In Angular8 i have a page which is listing some information and there is delete option after deleting rows from current page i need to refresh current page so that content may updated. I have used navigation for this but its not working due to same page navigation issue

[image]

below is my code for delete record

```
deleteBusiness(id) {    
    this.bs.deleteBusiness(id).subscribe(
      res =>{console.log(res)},
      error=>console.log(error.message),
      ()=>{this.router.navigate(['business'])}
    );    
  }
```

I have used `onSameUrlNavigation` in defined rotes but its not working.
Please let me know what is missed here
below is my route confirguration

```
const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: 'business/create',
    component: GstAddComponent
  },
  {
    path: 'business/edit/:id',
    component: GstEditComponent
  },
  {
    path: 'business',
    component: GstGetComponent,
    runGuardsAndResolvers: 'always'
  },
  {
    path: '',
    redirectTo: "/business",
    pathMatch :"full"
  },
];
```

I have used below links for going out of this probelm

[Angular 6 router link issue in the same page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52854256/angular-6-router-link-issue-in-the-same-page)

but got no success. Please suggest a way to go out of this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> i need to refresh current page so that content may updated

I think doing a refresh to update the data for a delete may not be ideal.

I would remove the deleted data from whatever the array is building what I would assume is in the `*ngFor`. Lets assume this is called business and is an array.

```
public business = []; // holds youd business objects.

public deleteBusiness(id): void
{    
    this.bs.deleteBusiness(id).subscribe(res => 
    {
        const toRemove = this.business.findIndex(data => data.id = id);

        if (toRemove !== -1)
        {
            this.business.splice(toRemove, 1);
        }

    },
    error => 
    { 
        console.log(error.message),
    }
    );    
}
```

This will ensure the view is up to date with the deleted item, then when the page does eventually refresh the deleted data wont be loaded again. Drop a comment if there are any issues.

[.findIndex()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/findIndex)

[.splice()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice)

Comment: Thank u so much :)

Answer (score 1):

you don't have to reload the page just to refresh the data. not since AJAX was invented!
when the delete promise resolves call the function that loads the data.

```
deleteBusiness(id) {    
    this.bs.deleteBusiness(id).subscribe(()=>{
         this.loadData();
    });    
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

`window.location.reload();` This reloads whole page,but it is better not to do that just for updating values either you can remove that value from array by doing splice `array.splice(index_value,1);` Or Just call the api that holds the result.

Answer (score 1):

```
deleteBusiness(id) {    
 this.bs.deleteBusiness(id).subscribe( (err,res) => {
   if(err){ /* Do Something */ }
   else{  
          /* Here call the function which fetch this list like */  
       this.functionName();
   }
 });    
}
```

Answer (score 0):

router.navigate() function is only called when there is a change in the URL, What you need to do is to get the response and trigger a getAll call if the response is SUCCESS.

// Assuming you have a function to get all data.

```
deleteBusiness(id) {    
    this.bs.deleteBusiness(id).subscribe(
      res =>{this.getAll()},
      error=>console.log(error.message),
      ()=>{this.router.navigate(['business'])}
    );    
  }
```

// Define getAll() if not exists